# Codeigniter 3 shows errors in production mode

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, error-reporting, php-7.3

I'm using Codeigniter 3 in production mode but errors are displayed. My web server is Wampserver 3.1.7 with it's default php.ini. How can I disable error reporting?

This is part of my index.php:

```php
    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');


    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(-1);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
            {
                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
            }
            else
            {
                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
            }
        break;

        default:
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
            exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
    }
```

And this is a part of the error I have:

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>

<p>Type: Error</p>
<p>Message: Call to a member function result() on bool</p>
<p>Filename: D:\Projects\Nafis Global System\Server\application\core\MY_Model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 377</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

Just some of errors are displayed. for example if the Mysqli connection did not established, this error is displayed:

> Message: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on bool

Comment: How you set the `production` environment? What you are getting when you do `echo ENVIRONMENT` in index.php?

Comment: I added definition line to the code

Comment: have you checked `echo ENVIRONMENT` value? it should be production.

Comment: @VinayPatil It's 'production' in MY_Controller.php

Answer (score 2):

The most common place to set `CI_ENV` is in `.htaccess` using the SetEnv directive, e.g.

```
SetEnv CI_ENV production
```

it's common practice to use a different .htaccess for the development server and live server. On the development box use

```
SetEnv CI_ENV development
```

The above relates to Apache servers which must also have the `env_module` enabled for `SetEnv` to work.

NGINX or other web servers use different mechanisms to set variables.

You should also adjust the database configuration for production. In particular the item `'db_debug`. The value assigned there can be set dynamically using the `ENVIRONMENT` variable too, e.g. in *application/config/database.php*

```
$db['default'] = array(
    //bunch of items,
    'db_debug' => ENVIRONMENT == 'development' ? true : false,
    //more items
);
```